# c : how to use system() to launch simultaneoulsy N programs but keeping N<N_processors

Tags: c, system, multiprocessing

I have a code called `mc` that I want to execute thousands of times with different input files. To call the code just one I type :

```
./mc -sim my_input_file
```

I'd like to write a small auxiliary program that allows me to run that program thousand times but in a way that it lunches only N times `mc` at a time (one execution per processor, assuming I have N processors)

What I've done so far is creating an auxiliary program that contains essentially :

```
unsigned int N_processors(8);
unsigned int m(0);
for(unsigned int i(0); i<1000;i++){
    system("./mc -sim " + file[i] +"&"); /*file[i] is the ith input file*/
    m++;
    while(m>=N_processors){ 
        usleep(1e6); 
        if(/*test condition*/){m--;}
     }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know by what I should replace `/*test condition*/`

Comment: Could you use OpenMP?

Comment: @meaning-matters I could but I'm not sure it will be a good idea sinc `mc` already uses OpenMP. What would be your idea ? (btw, I should have been more precise, when I call mc, I also precise the number of threads that it can use with OpenMP...)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Unix system, you'd better use fork() instead of system().
So you can check that a process is finished before launch another one.

Something like that :

```
unsigned int N_processors(8);
unsigned int m(0);
int status = 0;
pid_t* pID = new pid_t[pCount];
for(unsigned int i(0); i<1000;i++){
{
   pid= fork()
   if(!pid) // child process
    {   
     system("./mc -sim " + file[i] +"&"); /*file[i] is the ith input file*/
    } 
   else 
    {
     nbfork++;
     if(nbfork >= N_processors)
      {
        wait(&status);  // waiting for a child to finish before spawning another one
        nbfork--;
      }
    }
}
```

***Not tested***

Comment: Could you be more precise please ? I think your idea is excellent but I have never used fork()... I google it a few seconds ago and I saw that exec() is related to fork() but exec() keeps the same id.

Comment: @meaning-matters ... great help ;-)

Comment: precisions added up above

Comment: @LaurentNavet what is the `status` variable ? did you mean : `status = system("...")` ?

Comment: @PinkFloyd, no status is just a parameter needed by wait() and should be checked to ensure that the process has finished properly ( e.g not killed or segfault )

Comment: @LaurentNavet yeah but where does status come from ? is it a default variable that exists all the time ?